# External Javascript file fails to receive variables from javascript block in head

Tags: php, javascript

I've been searching the net for several hours and can't find an answer in the whole "external js file"-jungle. I hope you guys can help!

In short: My external javascript file doesn't seem to get the variables which I defined in the main.php file..

1. On **main.php** I define php variables and "transform" them into
   javascript variables

   ```
   <head>...
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var phpmain_img = <?php echo json_encode($main_img); ?>;
   var phpvar1_large = <?php echo json_encode($var1_large); ?>;
   var phpvar2_large = <?php echo json_encode($var2_large); ?>;
   var phpvar3_large = <?php echo json_encode($var3_large); ?>;
   var phpvar4_large = <?php echo json_encode($var4_large); ?>;
   </script>
   ...
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/wshop/ext.js"></script>
   </head>
   ```
2. In my **ext.js** file I want to process those variables. In the
       ext.js file I defined a the function swapImage() that will be used
       back in the main PHP:

   ```
           var imgArray = new Array(
           phpmain_img,
           phpvar1_large,
           phpvar2_large,
           phpvar3_large
           );

       function swapImage(imgID) {
           var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
           var newImg;
           newImg = imgArray[imgID];
           theImage.src = newImg;
       }

       function preloadImages() {      
           for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
               var tmpImg = new Image;
               tmpImg.src = imgArray[i];
           }
       }
   ```
3. Result: The swapImage() in the **main.php**... doesnt work

   ```
   <div id="image">
       <img id="theImage" src="<?=$main_img; ?>" alt="" />
   </div>

   <div id="thumbs">
   <?php

           echo "<img src=\"<$main_img_small\" alt=\"\" onmouseover=\"swapImage(0);\">";
           echo "<img src=\"$var1_small\" alt=\"\" onmouseover=\"swapImage(1);\">";
           echo "<img src=\"$var2_small\" alt=\"\" onmouseover=\"swapImage(2);\">";
           echo "<img src=\"$var3_small\" alt=\"\" onmouseover=\"swapImage(3);\">";

           ?>


       <br />
   </div>
   ```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I don't get a specific error, the swapImage functions doesn't work at mouseover. However, I tried to output the variables with e.g. `document.write(phpimg_main)` but nothing appears which makes me believe that there's something wrong with the handing over of the variables...

Here's the source code browser output

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="../demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            ....
</style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var phpmain_img = {"0":"http:\/\/path\/to\/main\/image.jpg"};
        var phpvar1_large = {"0":"http:\/\/path\/to\/image1.jpg"};
        var phpvar2_large = {"0":"http:\/\/path\/to\/image2.jpg"};
        var phpvar3_large = null;
        var phpvar4_large = null;
        </script>   

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/wshop/ext.js"></script>
</head>




<body onload="preloadImages()">

    <div id="image">
        <img id="theImage" src="http://path-to-main-image.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="thumbs">
    <img src="http://path-to-main-image.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(0);"><img src="http://path-to-image1.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(1);"><img src="http://path-to-image2.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(2);">

        <br />
    </div>



</body>
```

`

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks for your input and answers! Of course, you're right, I need a string and not an object, so the encoding is a great hint.

However the problem is still not solved with [0]. Even if I hardcode it like below, the second javascript block (which I tried to outsource as an external js-file before) doesn't get the variables defined in the first javascript block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var phpmain_img = "http://www.abc.de/path-img_main.jpg";
        var phpvar1_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img1.jpg";
        var phpvar2_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img2.jpg";
        var phpvar3_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img3.jpg";
        var phpvar4_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img4.jpg";
        </script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


                   var imgArray = new Array(
                phpmain_img,
                phpvar1_large,
                phpvar2_large,
                phpvar3_large,
                phpvar4_large
            );



            function swapImage(imgID) {
                var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
                var newImg;
                newImg = imgArray[imgID];
                theImage.src = newImg;
            }

            function preloadImages() {      
                for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
                    var tmpImg = new Image;
                    tmpImg.src = imgArray[i];
                }
            }



            </script>
```

**Browser Source View Output:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var phpmain_img = "http://www.abc.de/path-img_main.jpg";
        var phpvar1_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img1.jpg";
        var phpvar2_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img2.jpg";
        var phpvar3_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img3.jpg";
        var phpvar4_large = "http://www.abc.de/path-img4.jpg";
        </script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> //this i actually wanted to outsource into an external js-file

        var imgArray = new Array(
            phpmain_img,
            phpvar1_large,
            phpvar2_large,
            phpvar3_large,
            phpvar4_large
        );



        function swapImage(imgID) {
            var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
            var newImg;
            newImg = imgArray[imgID];
            theImage.src = newImg;
        }

        function preloadImages() {      
            for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
                var tmpImg = new Image;
                tmpImg.src = imgArray[i];
            }
        }



        </script>
```

Sorry, for the long topic here. I hope you can follow! I'm giving my best to learn!

Comment: Ugh, PHP and inline JS not a good idea... Don't know where your problem is but try attaching the event handler _in JavaScript_.

Comment: `doesn't work` doesn't tell anyone very much. What shows up in source view in browser? Are any errors thrown?

Comment: "doesn't work" is about as undescriptive as it gets. Do you get any errors in the browser?

Comment: try closing your image tags

Comment: You should right away declare and fill the `imgArray`. Numbered variables are never a good idea.

Comment: @charlietfl: Updated with browser output..hope this helps us!

Comment: not sure how you define your image variables in php but they are not strings as your javascript is expecting they are php array elements that are being added as javascript objects. You need strings output

Comment: Good point, @charlietfl, I've updated my answer. Is it OK now?

Comment: -1. Use a debugger, set breakpoint in your `swapImage()` function and step through it. If you want us to help you, write it into a fiddle and show us.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not PHP expert, did you possibly mean

```
var phpmain_img = "<?php echo urlencode($main_img); ?>";
```

instead of

```
var phpmain_img = <?php echo json_encode($main_img); ?>;
```

If you look at rendered markup, it is obvious that image variables don't contain what you expected:

```
var phpmain_img = {"0":"http:\/\/path\/to\/main\/image.jpg"};
```

Instead of a string, it is an object.

Comment: the quotes around output will turn the javacsript object into `var phpmain_img = "{"0":"http......}";` which is even worse as would need to parse to json in js also

Comment: I changed it to take `[0]` element and please note `urlencode`.

Comment: the `[0]` should work. My point is why is it even there in the defining of the value( part of OP code we can't see). The json_encode is likely doing the escaping. If not, `striplashes()` would make it readable instead of urlencode

Comment: good point with the string instead of object! getting closer..however, the javascripts after the one where the (php) variable is encoded to a javascript variable, seem to not recognize this variable..see update 2.

Comment: ..even if I put `document.write(phpmain_img)` into the second javascript, nothings happens.. it should be a global variable this way, so why isn't it displaying?

Comment: @nrodic , the php variables are simple strings, thus no need to access them via [..]. e.g.: `$main_img="http:....."`

Comment: @Franc OK, changed answer (again). Then it is `json_encode` causing problems.